# Is there an easy way to restore a factor object from its summary?

Tags: r

For example:

```
x <- c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C')
x <- as.factor(x)
print(summary(x))
```

will give the result:

```
A B C 
2 1 3
```

Now if I have a named vector:

```
nv <- c(A=2, B=1, C=3)
```

How can I easily retain the `x` in the above example without caring about their order?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your specific example, you can use `rep`, but **take care: this is not a general solution**.  In fact, I believe a general solution is impossible, because `summary` discards information about the original vector.

```
x <- factor(c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'))
xs <- summary(x)

rep(names(xs), times=xs)
[1] "A" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

---

The reason that this is not general is that `summary` really just give a contingency table, thus losing information about the position of the elements.  For example, if I take your vector and append a few more `A` characters to the end, look what happens:

```
x <- factor(c('A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A'))
xs <- summary(x)

rep(names(xs), times=xs)
[1] "A" "A" "A" "A" "B" "C" "C" "C"
```

(You now have a sorted vector with all of the correct elements, but not in the correct order.)

Comment: Thanks Anfrie ! Maybe I wasn't clear in my post, but I just need the vector without the order.

Comment: @Andrie is the `unname` necessary?

Comment: @pete No, you're correct - `unname` is superfluous in this case.  Answer edited.